# Htaccess Mod Rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want the following url:

```
http://localhost/new/post?url=sample-post-one
```

to Look Like this via htaccess mod_rewrite:

```
http://localhost/new/post/sample-post-one/
```

This might be a question asked already or a similar one but I have been trying to figure it out since a couple of hours and did not get to a solution.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update**
Here's what I've tried

```
<Files .htaccess,.svn> order allow,deny deny from all </Files>
Options +FollowSymlinks
# For Removing .php extension from files
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ post?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: added the following code to htaccess and it removed the ".php" extension:   RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Tried different codes that I found from different resources but I did not get to a conclusion perhaps

Comment: Couple of things, I've added your info about the rest of your `.htaccess` to your question. You'll have a lot better results if you provide every bit of information so people can help. Also your "question" still isn't technically asking a question (which is why it's being down ranked and potentially closed). It looks more like the "I can't do this and I'm not going to try, fix it."

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ 

seriously man I have been trying to get a solution since a couple of hours, If It was like I can't do this and I am not going to fix it, I would have never asked for help at the very first place

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ

Since I am determined and want to get done with this, therefore I had to ask this question, ask professionals if they can provide some hint or a solution to this problem

Comment: I'm saying it's all in presentation. If you said, "Can someone tell me what's wrong with my .htaccess? Here's what I've tried so far..." then listed your entire .htaccess, then explained what you're trying to do, it would have been answered hours ago. We're trying to blindly guess what's happening and most people assume you've posted the whole thing... without knowing if there is a competing rule. It's cool. Just trying to be helpful for next time.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ 

Alright I apologize for the bad presentation, now can you please provide a solution if you don't mind :)

Comment: @Mark have you tried my solution(s)? (from 27 minutes ago)

Comment: still facing that weird Internal Server Error, can you let me know how to fix this. I am using WAMP and have restarted Apache after making changes to the htaccess file.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ 

Yes I have tried to implement each and every solution provided to me on this page, but still getting the same 500 Internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([^/.]+)/?$ post?url=$1 [L]
```

Or better ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ post?url=$1 [L]
```

By the way, you should have a look to guides like [this one](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/).

Comment: Ditch the period. that matches all characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am still getting 500 Internal Server Error Here is the complete .htaccess script anyways

`<Files .htaccess,.svn>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymlinks

# For Removing .php extension from files
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ post?url=$1 [L]`

Comment: isn't there a problem with the '.php extension removal rule'. how does it work with resources like images, css ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use  below code:

```
http://localhost/new/post?url=sample-post-one
RewriteRule    ^post/([0-9]+)/?$    post?url=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle  post requests
```

and to get more information you can [refer to this](http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: It doesn't work, your code only rewrites for posts which are numeric values, not text.

Comment: It did not work, it says:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: you should only add regular expression to include all character  ([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) and if you are using any special charecter you can also do tha

Comment: may rewrite engine  not on  you server , if you are running lamp server you should check in phpinfo

Comment: If they're getting a 500 server error it's because of a redirect to a missing folder that loops constantly.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ,

This is all that I have in .htaccess file: 

`<Files .htaccess,.svn>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymlinks

# For Removing .php extension from files
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Rewrite rule
RewriteRule ^post/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ post?url=$1 [L]`

Comment: @Mark I've added that to your original question since that's where it goes. You've got competing rules.

Comment: if you are stil getting error please look  web server's error log

Answer (score 0):

Basically we're capturing the bit for the last folder. The rest can be hard coded. Also you should delete the competing rule. `^` indicates beginning of string. `$` is the end of the string. If you use both of those characters everything has to literally match except for the bits where we're using [REGEX](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) patterns for matching. Also everything is case sensitive.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/post/([^/]+)/?$ new/post?url=$1
```

If you know that you're only going to allow letters, numbers, periods, and hyphens, then you can do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^new/post/([^A-Za-z0-9.-]+)/?$ new/post?url=$1
```

If for some reason you're including `new/post` and `post` is really your [document root](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) it should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^A-Za-z0-9.-]+)/?$ ?url=$1
```

Apache is a well documented application. They provide an excellent resource with hundreds of examples on their site with explanations of each in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/).